# Removing scientific notation in excel

Tags: excel, notation

I have a spreadsheet which has 100s of rows but some of them have scientific notation which is quite giving a problem in calculations. Does anyone knows how to remove that...

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Like what does your data look like, where does it come from, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), etc.

Comment: In file 1 - Column A i have a list of IP adderess and Column B is the distance, Similarly i have 10s of such files. What i exactly want to do is to find overall CDF, how can i do that? Something like x-axis the distance and y-axis the IPs

Comment: Why is scientific notation a problem in calculations?  If I type (eg) "1e3" into a cell in Excel it correctly recognises it as 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [reformatting](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/2010-12-25-excel-2010-format-tutorial-pt-2_6.htm) the entire column?